# QGIS (maptool) Plugin Crashes on some computers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, pyqt5

I developed a custom Plugin which inherits from QGIS MapTool.The plugin has user interfaces and can add features to the map based on a GUI. The Plugin works Fine on some computer(when they installed QGIS with OSGeo4W). But on standalone version does not work and crashes and gives the following error.
[image]

The plugin loads without any error even show the GUI but when I click on the map to place feature it shows crashed.

The problem is I can not put the codes here as they are about 9000 line codes. 
Can anyone explain what is  QObject::Connect and QHashData::allocateNode

As no one understood the problem I decided to add more information:
I think there might be somthing wrong with the way I connect the signals:
here is my code for connecting signals:

```
 def __form_action_handler(self):
    """This Will handle the buttons action/ and field change  """

    self.main_dlg.OperationalMode_btn.clicked.connect(self._operation_mode)
    self.main_dlg.UGStructureType_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._form_info_change_handler)
    self.main_dlg.AddToList_tbtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.add_to_structure_to_add_list())
    #self.feature_list_dlg.remove_tbtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.remove_from_to_be_added_list_table())
    self.feature_list_dlg.remove_tbtn.clicked.connect(self.remove_from_to_be_added_list_table)
    self.main_dlg.Hierarchy_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','Hierarchy_cbo', "hierarchy"))
    self.main_dlg.Size_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','Size_cbo', "size"))
    self.main_dlg.Material_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','Material_cbo', "material"))
    self.main_dlg.ObjectStatus_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','ObjectStatus_cbo', "object_status"))
    self.main_dlg.PlantOwner_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','PlantOwner_cbo', "owner"))
    self.main_dlg.JointUse_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','JointUse_cbo', "joint_use"))
    self.main_dlg.SpaceOccupancy_cbo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','SpaceOccupancy_cbo', "space_occupancy"))


    self.main_dlg.NodeHousingID_txt.textChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','NodeHousingID_txt', "id"))
    self.main_dlg.AdditionalID_txt.textChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','AdditionalID_txt', "additional_id"))
    self.main_dlg.Lat_txt.textChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','Lat_txt', "Lat"))
    self.main_dlg.Long_txt.textChanged.connect(lambda:self.__single_field_vlaue_change_handler('self.main_dlg','Long_txt', "Long"))
```